# Pegar click de botão em várias linhas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu preciso pegar todos os clicks de um html gerado em um select.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<tr class="pesquisar" data-idlocalidade="<?php echo $linha['IDLocalidade']; ?>">
    <td class="NomeLocalidade"><?php echo $linha['NomeLocalidade']; ?></td>
    <td class="TelComercial1"><?php echo $linha['TelComercial1']; ?></td>
    <td class="Endereço"><?php echo $linha['EndLogradouro'].' - '.$linha['EndBairro']; ?></td>
    <td class="EndCidade"><?php echo $linha['EndCidade']; ?></td>
    <td class="acoes-linha">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <?php if (in_array("REGRA_ADMIN_PERFIL_EMPRESAS", $_SESSION['Autoridades'])) { ?> <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs default tooltips DefinirSede <?php echo (($linha['IDLocalidade']==$EmpresaInfo->_IDSede)?'disabled':''); ?>" data-container="body" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Defninir como Localidade Sede"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> </a> <?php }; ?>
            <!-- Aqui faria o envio para a pagina de edição--> <?php if (in_array("REGRA_ADMIN_PERFIL_EMPRESAS", $_SESSION['Autoridades'])) { ?> <a  class="btn btn-xs default tooltips Editar" id="EditarLocalidade" data-container="body" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> </a> <?php }; ?>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Ele me retorna um html normal.

Quando eu quero pegar o click de uma terceira, quarta linha, ele não identifica.

```
$("#EditarLocalidade").click(function(){
    alert("ooi");
})
```

O alert só aparece no primeiro campo, quando teria que aparecer em todos.

[image: Só funciona o da seta]

Só funciona o da seta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O atributo `id` deve ser único no formulário, nunca deve ser repetido. Você terá que obter por meio de outro seletor, como uma classe ou um atributo qualquer:

```
  $("a[data-original-title='Editar']").click(function(){
      alert("ooi");
  })
```

Comment: verdade, só mudei pra .Editar, que foi, valeu